# All valid values of an argument of a function in R

Tags: r, function, arguments

Suppose we have an R function whose arguments must be selected out of a finite set of elements. Like `qplot(..., geom="")`. And `geom` can take only some values, like `bar` or `point`.

How can I find out all the valid values the argument of a given function may take? Apart from docs or Internet, which often miss all possible values. Perhaps, some R function can help?

Comment: This is not possible in general as validity is often determined by the logic of the function in question.

Comment: Due to the way ggplot2 is developed, you can get the list using this: `sub("geom_","",apropos("^geom_"))`

Comment: Perhaps parsing the help page to get the Usage? Would not be 100%.

Answer (score 7):

If the function of interest is defined like

```
f <- function(a = c("foo","bar")) {
    match.arg(a)
}
```

i.e. when the options are defined as a vector to be later checked with `match.arg` function, then you could use the `formals` function which would give you a list of arguments with the values like in the following example

```
> formals(f)
$a
c("foo", "bar")
```

Otherwise I don't think it is possible to get all valid argument values without RTFSing.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Pavel Obraztcov's excellent answer (and @James' comment above), take this function `f` as an example:

```
f <- function(x) {
  if(x == "foo") {
    return("you said 'foo'")
  } else if(x == "bar") {
    return("you said 'bar'")
  } else if(x == "xyz") {
    stop("'xyz' is not a valid option")
  }
}
```

(Not necessarily a *good* function, but there's nothing to stop someone from writing a function like this.)

How would we want to define "valid values" for the argument `x`?  We could say the valid values are `foo`, `bar`, and `xyz`, since `f` explicitly handles those three values.  But it's clearly insufficient to just write a piece of code that parses a series of simple if-else statements; not all functions are structured this way.

And `f` handles `xyz` by throwing an error, so maybe only `foo` and `bar` are valid values?  But in that case, we need a piece of code that will examine the internal logic of `f` and determine that `xyz` always leads to an error.  That's not a trivial task - and I'm no CS expert, but it occurs to me to wonder whether the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) comes into play here.

Also, `f` does nothing for values other than `foo`, `bar`, and `xyz` - that's probably bad in this context, but are there contexts where both "return something" and "do nothing" would be acceptable ("valid") outcomes?

Things would be even worse if `f` didn't handle `x` directly, but instead passed it to some other function.  Now we need to trace the internal logic of `f` *and* any functions it calls.

So no, there's no general algorithmic way to get all valid options for some argument.  When documentation and the internet fail, reading the source code (as a human) *is* the general way.

Comment: There is no `elif` keyword in R. You are thinking about Python.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this **particular** question is probably

```r
apropos("^geom_") |> gsub(pattern = "geom_", replace = "")
```

but this is a special case: to know this you need to know that `qplot` (which is now deprecated) looks up a `geom_` function: this internal code line shows what it's doing (`g` is a loop variable set to the values in `geom`):

```r
p <- p + do.call(paste0("geom_", g), params)
```

```
 [1] "abline"            "area"              "bar"              
 [4] "bin_2d"            "bin2d"             "blank"            
 [7] "boxplot"           "col"               "contour"          
[10] "contour_filled"    "count"             "crossbar"         
[13] "curve"             "density"           "density_2d"       
[16] "density_2d_filled" "density2d"         "density2d_filled" 
[19] "dotplot"           "errorbar"          "errorbarh"        
[22] "freqpoly"          "function"          "hex"              
[25] "histogram"         "hline"             "jitter"           
[28] "label"             "line"              "linerange"        
[31] "map"               "path"              "point"            
[34] "pointrange"        "polygon"           "qq"               
[37] "qq_line"           "quantile"          "raster"           
[40] "rect"              "ribbon"            "rug"              
[43] "segment"           "sf"                "sf_label"         
[46] "sf_text"           "smooth"            "spoke"            
[49] "step"              "text"              "tile"             
[52] "violin"            "vline"
```

Answer (score 0):

str(function_name) can be very informative e.g.

```
str(acf)
function (x, lag.max = NULL, type = c("correlation", "covariance", "partial"), plot = TRUE, na.action = na.fail, 
    demean = TRUE, ...)
```