# How do I find a list of the acceptable options for a given argument in an R function?

Tags: r

Specifically, I wanted to know what other options I have for `ggplot2::geom_smooth(stat = "x")`. I know x can be "smooth" or it can be "identity", but what else can it be? It wasn't in the documentation and I haven't had luck googling it.

What I really want is a general way to find this out given an argument in any function. Obviously the function is checking your entry against some list, so where is that list?

1. Check the documentation. This works sometimes, but not in the case of `geom_smooth()` or `layer()`.
2. Google it. This works perfectly for `glm(family = )`, but again not for the stat argument in `layer()`
3. Follow the code. If I look at the code for `layer`, I see

   ```
   stat <- check_subclass(stat, "Stat", env = parent.frame())
   ```

   but `check_subclass()` doesn't have a help page, so it's a dead end for me.
4. Ask StackOverflow. This is what I'm trying to avoid. Is there some way to get R to return the list of available options, or a sure fire way to find the list hidden in the package somewhere?

I would gladly accept someone giving me the answer for stat options, but what I really want is a general method, so I can find this information for any function.

Comment: In principle, any stat in ggplot, but most of them would be nonsensical and so either produce nonsense or an error, usually telling you that you've omitted an aesthetic that would normally be expected for that stat. For instance, `stat = "quantile"` is probably usually reasonable, and I can get lots of others to "work" be including the necessary aesthetics, but the output is usually nonsense.

Comment: (A perfectly general method doesn't exist; the documentation is always the first best option. After that you have to start asking either the source code, Google or other humans.)

Comment: The reason is because how acceptable inputs for a function are checked can vary hugely depending on implementation, it isn't always checking against a list so simply. For some reason I could not find it on github, but you can see the source of `check_subclass` by simply typing `ggplot2:::check_subclass` into the console. If you supply a string, then it looks for some object with that name in the parent environment, and without diving further into internals I don't know which environment that would be

Comment: As a general comment:  if the documentation isn't good enough, look for other documentation.  For example, there's a book about `ggplot2`:  https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2-book.  But if that fails (and I don't think it will for `ggplot2`), you might want to think about using a package that has better documentation.

Comment: @CalumYou I didn't know to put the third colon. That did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

A quick-and-dirty way to list available `ggplot2` stats:

```
ls("package:ggplot2") %>%
  data.frame(f.name = .) %>%
  filter(grepl("^stat_", f.name)) %>%
  mutate(stat.name = gsub("^stat_", "", f.name)) %>%
  pull(stat.name)
```

The general question about finding valid options for a given function argument has been asked a few times; [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20352842/all-valid-values-of-an-argument-of-a-function-in-r/69576620#69576620) is the earliest example I know of.  Unfortunately, as noted in the comments above, it's just not possible.