# How to find all options for individual arguments in R?

Tags: r, officer

I'm trying to use the `add_slide()` function in the `officer` package, and one argument is `layout`. How do I see all the possible options for this argument or any other? I know how to see all arguments for a function, such as by using `args(add_slide)` or `help(add_slide)`, but that doesn't show me all the possible options for that particular argument. For instance, in the `family` argument for `glm()`, you could specify `"poisson"`, `"binomial"`, etc.

Though my question concerns add_slide() specifically, I'm interested in how to solve this more broadly than this specific case.

Comment: In your case the possible options for layout depend on the `pptx` template you are working with, e.g. for the default pptx template shipped with officer you could get the available layout options via `officer::layout_summary(officer::read_pptx())`

Comment: There is not one method that will work for every function. Note that CRAN is full of packages written by different authors and not everyone does things the same way. Ideally the information you desire should be in the help page for that function, but documentation is written by different authors with different standards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All valid values of an argument of a function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20352842/all-valid-values-of-an-argument-of-a-function-in-r)